# problem with showing cluster info when trying to acces elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

[image]

showing cluster info when trying to acces elasticsearch in my browser

Comment: Do you wanna do a search ? What's you purpose ?

Comment: no....i just want to access to kibana dashboard and it only shows me this cluster info

Answer (score 0):

1.You should install kibana, download url is https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases#kibana

2.start kibana

```
./bin/kibana
```

3.access url http://localhost:5601/

4.create your dashboard.